# Get membership for list of computers

Tags: powershell

I have been using the following command to pull the list of membership for a given machinename:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity (Get-ADComputer <MACHINENAME>) 
| select-object name | Out-File C:\mydir\MemberShip.csv
```

The membership identifies software associated to a machine such as Adobe Acrobat Pro, MS Project, etc. Sometimes the software is associated but not actually installed which is why I use the query to validate this information against another list. I am trying to run a query to pull the membership for a list of assets in a text file and export with the name of each computer and the membership for each as well. Maybe get it to display something like the following:

```
NAME            NAME
-----------     -------------
<MACHINENAME1>  ADOBE ACROBAT PRO
                MS PROJECT STD
                MS VISIO PRO

<MACHINENAME2>  ADOBE ACROBAT PRO
                ADOBE PHOTOSHOP
```

I have tried the following but I get a few errors:

```
$computers = Get-Content .\computers.txt 
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership ForEach ($computer in $computers) 
{Get-ADComputer $computer} | select-object operatingSystem, name | 
Out-Gridview
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you get the membership and computer name, then you can iterate thru the membership, generate a PSCustomObject that has the wanted properties, send that out to your collection, and finally `Export-CSV` with it. that will give you a CSV file with each row holding `ComputerName, GroupName`. you will have multiple rows when a computer has multiple memberships, but that is easy to deal with when you want to make a custom _display_ of the data. [*grin*] data 1st, presentation 2nd ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$computers = Get-Content .\computers.txt 

$results = foreach ( $computer in $computers ) {

        $adcomputerproperties = get-adcomputer -Identity $computer -Properties *
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adcomputerproperties.DistinguishedName 
        | select @{n="Computername";e={ $computer}},Name,@{n="OperatingSystem"; e={ $adcomputerproperties.OperatingSystem}}  } 


$results | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Yadav, thank you for assistance. What you shared did actually display in the Gridview w/ the associated machine name and a line for each membership with the OS. Thank you! So where you have it collecting computername, OS, etc, I can add additional fields to capture additional information?

Comment: Strangely enough it is no longer working Giving 
```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At line:5 char:1
+ Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adcomputerproperties.Distin ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~```

Comment: you can add additional fields to capture more information. pass output from Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity <distinguished name for any single computer> | get-member . It will output methods and properties for the command. you can use one of these properties in select command or can create custom properties like I have created for operating system.

Comment: I have tested above code in my test environment. It should work flawlessly. Is there any change in code. you can also debug the code in Powershell ISE.

Comment: It seems to be a hit or miss with Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership working. I haven't changed anything. It worked at first, then stopped, then starting working again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. You could put it in a script, function or whatever.

```
$results = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
$computers = Get-Content .\computers.txt

$computers | ForEach-Object {
    $ComputerObject = Get-ADComputer $_
    $obj = @{
        Computername = $_
        OS = $ComputerObject.OperatingSystem
    }

    $obj.Memberships = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ComputerObject | select-object name 

    $results.Add($obj) | Out-Null
}

return $results
```

Comment: Fonta, thank you for your recommendation. I tried the following and received this as a result.

The term 'Computername' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. It says this for the term 'OS' and 'Memberships' as well.

Comment: Do you think that may not have the function lined up properly in powershell? Noticed that with Yadav recommendation above.

Comment: I used () instead of {}. Silly me.